# Kill Application Process Without Windows Error Reporting

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to completely kill the current process and skip Windows Error Reporting? Or even a way to handle global errors in a more friendly way so that the exception is not passed to the OS?

I handle as many errors as I can locally, but also have a global error handler that will send me an email with the details of the error.  This is my customized error reporting.

I have a WPF C# application that I have built for my company. It's used only by a handful of people.

I'm trying to find a way to make a more friendly message that says an error has been thrown and the application must close, sends the email, and then closes the application. But no matter what I do, the application still freezes and tries to report the error to Microsoft.

Comment: please show us the code

Comment: It is the manner in which you do it, don't keep that a secret when you ask questions here.  There isn't much to it, write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and do **not** allow it to return.  Call Environment.Exit() after you reported the error.

Comment: Your solution worked, @HansPassant. Environment.Exit(0);

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can and sometimes you cannot.

First you have to exam what exception causes your application crashing from event viewer and to see whether you can handle such an exception. Many exceptions can be handled by App.DispatcherUnhandledException and AppDomain.UnhandledException event handlers.

However some exceptions cannot be caught by user such as ExecutionEngineException. In these cases, you cannot prevent crashing and handle it gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add gloabl exception handlers at `Application` and `AppDomain` level.

Application level handler:

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;

void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs eventArgs)
{
        // exception handling goes here
}
```

AppDomain level handler:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnAppDomainUnhandledException;

void OnAppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs eventArgs)
{

}
```

However, there are few exceptions types (like StackOverflowException) that cannot be handled.